# Button not shown swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am new to swift coding, when I am trying to add a button by code, it does not show up in the Simulator.

I changed the dimension of the View in main.storyboard to 375*1114
there are scroll view and view inside with the same dimension as well.
there are also 5 collection views too.
These are all setup by the storyboard.

The code I used:

```
    let fullScreenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
    let plusButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
    plusButton.frame = CGRect(x: 300, y: 600, width: 50, height: 50)
    plusButton.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * plusButton.bounds.size.width
    plusButton.clipsToBounds = true
    plusButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "plus.png"), for: .normal)
    plusButton.center = CGPoint(x: fullScreenSize.width * 0.9, y: fullScreenSize.height * 0.9)
    plusButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(plusButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(plusButton)
```

I was trying to let the button to stay at the right bottom corner of the simulator all the time. How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Add button as the subView of the View of ScrollView!

Comment: try with `self.view.bringSubview(toFront: plusButton)`

Comment: Run the app in the debugger and then tap on the "view debugger" button (see WWDC 2016 [Visual Debugging with Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/410/) about 5 minutes into the video). Then you can figure out where it is and from there you should be able to easily debug the issue.

Comment: @Rob I think now its name is -"Debug View Hierarchy".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is  fine and correct add the background color and check once the button will be visibile else check your `plusButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "plus.png"), for: .normal)` **plus.png** is correct or not

```
plusButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
```

for full code

```
let fullScreenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
    let plusButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
    plusButton.frame = CGRect(x: 300, y: 600, width: 50, height: 50)
    plusButton.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * plusButton.bounds.size.width
    plusButton.clipsToBounds = true
    plusButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "normal.jpg"), for: .normal)
    plusButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    plusButton.center = CGPoint(x: fullScreenSize.width * 0.9, y: fullScreenSize.height * 0.9)
  //  plusButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(plusButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(plusButton)
```

output
[image]

Comment: I think you need to add button to subview (UIView) of scrollview, not the self.view.

Comment: how can I do this process? Thanks.

Comment: @szeto1121 - pardon

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik how can I add button to subview of scrollview?

because the button is still not shown when I run it. I think I need to add it on the Scrollview

Comment: @szeto1121 - you want to place the UIbutton as stable on UIView or yu need the moveable button on scrollview

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik stable on UIView that is under the ScrollView

Comment: @szeto1121 - change the View Hiearchy form UIView --> uibutton --> uiscrollview to   UIView  --> uiscrollview --> uibutton , surely works

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik but I don't know why I cannot find the UIButton in the View Hierarchy

Comment: @szeto1121 - your scrollview hierarchy is different and butoon in view hiearchy is different, else attach your project i will resolve your issue

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I have sent you an email. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to take an Outlet of `UIView` inside `UIScrollview` you already have in you `UIViewController` and add that button as a `subView` of that `UIView`. That's why your button is hiding, why don't you check it by looking at the View Hierarchy!

[image]

Comment: how can I add the button created by code to the View Hierarchy? Thanks.

Comment: It will be added automatically to the layer of View Hierarchy if you add subView of any UIElement. Did you take the Outlet of UIView i.e. inside your UIScrollView?